# Appending elements increases div's width visually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever I append new element the div's width will increase. I want it to act as a static one. Why don't I just put it to static pixel value? Well I need to have it working on all monitors and resolutions. I need the width of 100% so it goes to the right border and after appending it acts as the static one letting me scroll through the div.

In JSFiddle I set the width to 50% so you can see how it acts(In real environment it will be 100%) Try clicking 10 or more times on Add Tab to see what's happening. After that change the width to static one to see how I want it to behave.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/272p06ng/4/)

Change this code:

```
.l_tabs {
  height: 57px;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  /*Changing this to px works as i want it to work but then i have screen resolution problems   TRY to set the width to 500px to see*/
  background: #474544 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: maybe position:absolute?

Comment: I don't get what's the problem. Your fiddle already scrolls through the div with width 100%.

Comment: Yes. For me too it is working as you described.

Comment: Thanks position:absolute did the work!